# Placement of a "const double NA = 1e-300" errors out in header for Cocoa-Touch but not Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I tried to place `const double NA = 1e-300;` in the header file for Cocoa-Touch but Xcode doesn't like it.  However when I did this in Cocoa(64 bit MAC), it works just fine.

????????

Errors:

---

> Duplicate symbol _NA in
>   /Users/jdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iExperiment-chcmotcyeolxeacnidtlgofkcihz/Build/Intermediates/iExperiment.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iExperiment.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
>   and
>   /Users/jdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iExperiment-chcmotcyeolxeacnidtlgofkcihz/Build/Intermediates/iExperiment.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iExperiment.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>   for architecture i386

---

> Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

const double NA = 1e-300; // <------------- Error in Cocoa-Touch but not Cocoa ??  
// So where do I put this so it doesn't error out in Cocoa-Touch?? 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextView *tvText;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants defined in header files should look like this:

```
__unused static const double NA = 1e-300;
```

The `__unused` is to suppress compiler warnings for unused variables, and the `static` prevents the constant being exposed to the linker, which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get an error is that you're declaring and defining a variable named "NA" in each .m file that includes the .h file. So the linker gets two variables with the same name, and that's against the rules. (C++/ObjC++ has extra rules for dealing with that, but they don't come into play for C/ObjC.)

If you don't care about having an actual variable, you can use the preprocessor, as kuba's answer described.

If you want an actual variable, you have to decide whether you want the variable to be shared by all compilation units, or to have a separate copy in each compilation unit. In other words, do you want an extern variable, or a static variable?

For extern:

ViewController.h:

```
extern const double NA;
```

ViewController.m:

```
const double NA = 1e-300;
```

For static:

ViewController.h:

```
static const double NA = 1e-300;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you a define:

```
#define NA 1e-300
```

to define any constant expression. This will solve all linking issues, since the value is "placed into" the code that uses it, instead of making it a (constant) variable.

Comment: when using "#define" doubles can't be used, only integers... at least for some compiliers

Comment: @jdl: That's not true. #define defines macros, which are just text substitution. Everywhere NA appears in the code, the preprocessor will replace it with 1e-300, before the parser even gets to it. The preprocessor doesn't even look at what the value actually is, much less assign a type to it. (You're probably confusing it with #if statements, which do require integers.)